# Showing Form in own thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I want to show a little loading form while some time consuming operations are beeing performed in die main UI. More specific I'm importing an UI changing theme that will take a while (2-3 secounds) to perform it's changes.

However, it's no problem if the UI is blocked while it's loading but to instruct the user to wait I want to display an WaitForm that is beeing closed if the UI Thread has finished the loading process.

Here's how I thought it might work:

```
static class WaitDialogManager
{
    private static bool _isVisible { get; set; } = false;

    private static Task _task;

    public static void ShowDialog()
    {
        if (!_isVisible)
        {
            _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                WaitDialog _dialog = new WaitDialog();

                _isVisible = true;
                _dialog.Show();

                do
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                } while (_isVisible);

                _dialog.Hide();
                _dialog.Dispose();
                _dialog = null;
            });
        }
    }

    public static void CloseDialog()
    {
        _isVisible = false;
    }
}

private void UpdateUI() 
{
    WaitDialogManager.ShowDialog();

    SetUpUI();

    WaitDialogManager.CloseDialog();
}
```

Unfortunately it seems like the different thread has no effect?! Form is beeing loaded and showed but all winforms consits of white rectangles and no marquee progress bar is beeing showed.

Why is this? And how can I change the construct to make it work?

Thanks in advance, ADP

Comment: Won't _dialog.Show(); block ? Why have you got the do loop after that ?

Comment: This is pretty fundamentally wrong code, not just because your thread is stuck in a loop and always sleeping so not taking care of painting.  You also get to debug [this kind of problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/).  If that blog post does not make sense to you then *never* do this.  Instead let a worker thread run the slow code instead of the UI thread.  So a wait dialog can be a completely normal UI window.  Use the Task or BackgroundWorker class.

Comment: I think you're doing it backwards!  Don't put your form in a task, put the long running operation in the task.

Comment: You *can't* show a form in a non-UI thread, nor should you need to. The user isn't going to click on two buttons simultaneously. If you want to execute code in parallel, use eg. Task.Run and/or asynchronous event handlers, eg: `async void SomeButton_OnClick(...){await Task.Run(....);}`

Comment: As I stated: There is no chance to do anything in any worker thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above creating a thread is a stupid idea! (Thanks to those giving people minus just because they are beginners and lack some knowlegde on different topics - as it's normal for beginners. Thank god there are somewhere such perfect people who never had to lern and knew everything from the moment of birth...)

However, a simple Refresh call ensured the form to be visible. It's doing exactly what I needed.